# Storing Web Socket sessions in Redis

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, redis

I have a Web Socket Server Endpoint deployed in tomcat as follows:

```
    @ServerEndpoint(value="/alerts/{username}/{sessionId}/{token}",
    decoders = AlertDTODecoder.class, 
    encoders = AlertDTOEncoder.class )
public class AlertWebSocketEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, 
            @PathParam("username") String username, 
            @PathParam("sessionId") String sessionId,
            @PathParam("token") String token) throws IOException {

        String origToken = TokenCacheServiceImpl.getInstance().getToken(username, sessionId);

        if ( origToken == null || !origToken.equals(token)) {           
            session.close();
        }else {    
            AlertSession.getInstance().addUserSession(username, session);
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, @PathParam("username") String username) throws Exception {    
        AlertSession.getInstance().removeUserSession(username, session);        
        session.close();
    }
}
```

AlertSession is a singleton class where I maintain a cache of the sessions.

TokenCacheServiceImpl uses to cache Token corresponding to each user in REDIS.

I can't store Session in REDIS since it is a Non-Serializable object and hence have to maintain it in local memory. I am looking to avoid this since I don't want to lose data if server is restarted or if I want to do load balancing.

How can this be acheived?

Comment: Write your own serializer?  redis is not necessarily a persistent storage so you may lose data regardless.

Comment: Suppose redis is persistent. Then is there any way to store the Session object?

Comment: Eventually everything is subject to be broken, lost, stolen, demagnetized, decommissioned, etc.  Serialize a `session` whatever that means and then if it's not excessively large, store it as a redis string.  In redis a string a binary array with a length prefix, not necessarily a-zA-z0-9.  Serialize on write, deserialize on read.  See the NetDataContractSerializer if you are using .net for a discussion.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2  I have worked on a system that uses this to cache anything.  Java??

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to store arbitrary, non-`serializable` objects without a ton of work.

But if you know what kind of objects you are already storing, then you can certainly write your own serializer. There's nothing that says the data must be binary. You can use XML, JSON, or some made-up storage system.

Can you restrict your application so that is only stored certain types of objects? If you, for example, only store primitives (well, their boxed flavors) and collections or those things, you could do this with very little code. If not, be prepared to write more code.

It might be easier to change the code of your session objects to be `Serializable` and then just use Java serialization to get the job done.

Note that the future of Java serialization is uncertain. A very old JEP was filed to remove serialization, but [it was withdrawn](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/154). More recent security concerns have prompted some to [support the removal of serialization from future Java versions](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3275924/java/oracle-plans-to-dump-risky-java-serialization.html). That second article specifically mentions that "[r]emoving serialization is a long-term goal and is part of [Project Amber](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/)", but I don't see anything in Project Amber that deals with Serialization *at all*.

Also, certain existing Java specifications (parts of Java EE, including the Servlet spec) pretty much *require* the support for Serialization, so... even if it's deprecated, I don't see it going anywhere anytime soon.